# Limes $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^{3/2}(\arctan(\sqrt{n+1})-\arctan\sqrt{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How to deal with the the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^{3/2}(\arctan(\sqrt{n+1})-\arctan\sqrt{n})$$
I'm clueless.

Comment: Hint: $\arctan \alpha + \arctan\beta=\arctan\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{1-\alpha\beta}\right)$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $\tan(x-y)=\frac{\tan x-\tan y}{1+\tan x\tan y}$ to express $\arctan(\sqrt{n+1})-\arctan(\sqrt{n})$ as
$$\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{1+\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n}}\right).$$
Rationalize the numerator, and you should be on your way.

You will probably want to write $n^{3/2}$ as $\frac{1}{1/n^{3/2}}$. The rest is closely related to the limit as $t\to 0$ of $\frac{\tan t}{t}$.

Comment: There's a typo in your first equation: the denominator should be a sum, not a difference.

Comment: Many thanks, fixed, luckily it did not affect the rest, where the $+$ was used.